# Recovering the Alon-Kleitman (p,q)-theorem for convex sets from a corollary

Tags: combinatorics, convex-analysis

## Definitions

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of sets.

- For any $p\geq q$, we say that $\mathcal{C}$ has the *$(p,q)$-property* if, for any $p$ sets in $\mathcal{C}$, one can find $q$ among them that intersect, i.e. if for any $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{C}$ with $|\mathcal{S}|=p$ there exists $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{S}$ with $|\mathcal{F}|=q$ such that $\cap\mathcal{F}\neq\emptyset$.
- A *transversal* $T$ of $\mathcal{C}$ is a set that intersects every set in $\mathcal{C}$.

## Results

[Alon and Kleitman](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/pq.pdf) proved the following, solving a long standing conjecture of Hadwiger and Debrunner.

> For any $p\geq q >d$, there exists some $n$ such that any **finite** family of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R^d}$ with the $(p,q)$-property has a transversal of size $n$.

This [can be generalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649257/if-every-finite-subfamily-of-mathcalf-has-a-transversal-of-size-n-does) to the following.

> For any $p\geq q >d$, there exists some $n$ such that that any family of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R^d}$ with the $(p,q)$-property can be partitioned into $n$ subfamilies, each having the finite intersection property.

Now, consider the following statement, which we label Statement ($\dagger$).

> For any $p\geq q >d$ and any family $\mathcal{C}$ of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R^d}$ with the $(p,q)$-property, there exists some $n$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ can be partitioned into $n$ subfamilies, each having the finite intersection property.

## Question

Can the Alon-Kleitman theorem be recovered from Statement ($\dagger$), i.e. is there an argument that makes it a corollary of Statement ($\dagger$)?

Answer (score 1):

It follows if you are willing to go to higher dimensions.
Assume for a contradiction that there is no universal $n$ that would work for all families.
Then for every $n$, take a family $\mathcal C_n$ with the $(p,q)$-property that requires at least $n$ points to stab.
The union of these families obviously requires an infinite number of points to stab, so it would violate Statement (†).
However, the union might not satisfy the $(p,q)$-property.
But by slightly modifying the families, we can achieve that collections from different families also satisfy it.
First of all, there is the standard trick of setting $p:=p^2$ so that the condition remains true also for multisets of size $p$.
Next, place each $\mathcal C_n$ on a different $d$-dimensional flat that are embedded to $\mathbb R^{pd}$, and replace each set $C\in\mathcal C_n$ with $C\times X_n$, where $X_n$ is a $(p(d-1))$-flat perpendicular to the $d$-flat of $\mathcal C_n$, so with a direct product of $C$ and a $\mathbb R^{p(d-1)}$.
This does not affect that we need $n$ points to stab $\mathcal C_n$.
If our $d$-flats are in general position, then this guarantees that the $(p,q)$-property still holds, as general $(p(d-1))$-flats intersect.